# What does the equivalent in mongoDB to return an array which contains the field name?

Tags: codeigniter, mongodb

mysql function in Codeigniter I Use list_field() to return an array containing the field names. What does the equivalent in mongoDB to return an array which contains he field name?
This code below I use the list_field function

```
function GetField($execution) {
    $query = $this->db->query($execution);
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        return $query->list_fields();
    } else {
        return array();
    }
}
```

My goal is if there is input with complex queries, the column appears dynamically in accordance with the input query

---

So the point I want to create applications such as rockmongo & phpMyAdmin. So when we enter a query, the results matching the query which we enter. Well I still have not found a function that bson field of MongoDB appear dynamically according to the query given by user.
example the query like this below :

```
db.users.find({}, {a:1,b:1})
```

so the bson field that appears is a and b.

Comment: as I understood you need to build a kind of query editor and you want to see "field names" while composing a query?

Answer (score 1):

There is NO equivalent query in MongoDB. It is a schema-less database, which means that every document can have totally different set of fields.

Comment: the field appears dynamically in accordance with the input query like using phpmyadmin in MySQL & rockmongo in mongoDB.
If there is no equivalent query in MongoDB, Is there a trick to solve my problem?

Comment: Sorry, didn't understand that. Can you elaborate?

Comment: So the point I want to create applications such as rockmongo & phpMyAdmin. So when we enter a query, the results matching the query which we enter. Well I still have not found a function that bson field of MongoDB appear dynamically according to the query given by user.
example the query like this below :

    db.users.find({}, {a:1,b:1})

so the bson field that appears is a and b.

Comment: If you execute this query, then you'll select ALL documents with only `_id`, `a` and `b` fields (if they exist in a document, of course).

Comment: so how to display the bson field dynamically with codeigniter?

Comment: I don't know codeigniter, but, I suppose, it's the same as everywhere. You get something from the DB and generate some UI out of it. Simple!

Answer (score 0):

The **find** method returns a cursor iterating which you will get a result which in turn depending on a driver may be a hash-table or a dictionary where its keys are the names of a document's attributes.

something like that:

```
{"name" : "John","age" : 30, "_id" : "497ce96f395f2f052a494fd4"}
```

so that "field names" would be "name","age","_id"

**Please Note**

Since Mongo is schema-less for each document in a query there may be different keys.

Comment: So is there a trick to solve my problem? because my application will receive complex queries. thanks in adnvance

Comment: the trick will be when in the document there is an embedded document which means other dictionary in the main one and you need smartly parse that tree-view.

Comment: this code below, for search a particular data
$collection->find(array('nama'=>'dendie'));

Comment: this code below, for search a particular data

<code>$collection->find(array('name'=>'dendie'));<code>

but this code static, how to change this dynamically. I mean if there is a field to input name and then I click submit button to search data